# Creating a VPN Tunnel between website and the server

Tags: networking, vpn, web, vlc-media-player

The machine which is connected in server LAN has the IP Camera Connected. From server the IP camera video feed can be viewable. I would like to view this IP camera from anywhere on the world through internet. So on the webpage i can embed any player like vlc to view.

But the problem is the IP camera doesnt have the static IP address.

So i guess using VPN connection if the website or web browser which i browsing the server page belongs to the server LAN then i can able to view the IP camera.

Am i clear ? Let me know the solutions or suggestions.

Comment: hey, why do you cross post? http://serverfault.com/questions/57121/creating-a-vpn-tunnel-between-website-and-the-server

Answer (score 1):

You need a dynamic IP address service like DynDNS.com
No VPNs should be necessary.